# How to validate all the fields in c# in windows application?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a windows form it has 8 textboxes , 3 combobox and a radio button. 
I am using this code but it does not work.

I put the beakpoint and checked the control does not go inside if(Cnt is TextBox) It is evaluating to false. I am keeping all the controls in the panel. May be because of this I am having a problem

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control cnt in this.Controls)
        {
            if (cnt is TextBox)
            {
                if (cnt.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("TextBox is Blank.");
                    cnt.BackColor = Color.Pink;
                }
            }
            else if (cnt is ComboBox)
            {
                ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)cnt;
                if (cmb.SelectedItem == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Combox is not Selected.");
                    cnt.BackColor = Color.Plum;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you format that correctly?
What does &quot;it doesn&#39;t work&quot; mean? Have you debugged it step by step?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx

Comment: If you're “keeping all the controls in the panel“ then you need to loop through the controls in the panel, not in `this.Controls`.

Comment: The logical structure of the controls on a form is a *tree*.  Trees are best visited with recursive code, write a method that takes a ControlCollection argument.  Recurse by passing a control's Controls property.